# iOS Observatory not discovered after 30 seconds. Error launching application on iPhone

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm unable to debug a freshly created app on physical iOS devices when pubspec dependencies reach a certain size, because it causes the "waiting for observatory port" step to timeout after 30 seconds.

Devices tested:
iPhone 12,
iPhone 12 Pro

iOS versions tested:
14.7.1,
14.5

The app runs properly on emulator but not on ios real device.
How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This Error message occur when your iPhone is busy processing something. For example as below.

If you run Flutter doctor you will see message as below.

Error: iPhone X is busy: Fetching debug symbols for iPhone X. Xcode will continue when iPhone X is finished. (code -10)

To confirm I opened xCode -> windows -> Devices and Simulator and it was showing the progress. Let the progress complete and then confirm by running Flutter doctor to make sure there is no error message.

Comment: It happened after I was clear about the Xcode cache. This answer is work for me.

Comment: Good answer. What I had to do though was unpair the device from 'xCode -> windows -> Devices and Simulator` then repair it and it worked

Answer (score 37):

Had the same problem after updating Xcode and running for the first time. As mentioned on the this github issue (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72161#issuecomment-994653225) I simply:

- Opened ios/Runner.xcworkspace with the iPhone connected
- Waited until "Fetching debug symbols" process finished
- Closed Xcode
- Run again from IDE and it worked!

Comment: This worked for me just updated to iOS 16 and Xcode 14

Comment: Worked for me. Waited around 5 min in Xcode to finish fetching symbols and indexing. After was able to run with real device immediately.

Comment: this only works on real devices? and doenst in the simulator?

Answer (score 13):

I have encountered the same issue and following this process has fixed the problem for me on 14.7.1 and 14.8:

> Uninstall the app
>
> Restart the phone
>
> Open the app using Xcode
>
> Run 'flutter clean' for the project
>
> Now it should work if you run it again.

If it still doesn't work you could try increasing the observatory timeout (the default appears to be 30 seconds):

```
localUri = await observatoryDiscovery.uri.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 30));
```

I'm not 100% sure why this problem appears inconsistently, but there is a lot of related discussion at the following link:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72161

Comment: This fixed the issue for me after I had updated Xcode.

Answer (score 10):

For coders who are as lazy as me, you could take these steps:

1. Open xcode for the project:
   [image]
2. Run the project from xcode:

[image]

3. while(prompt_below_finished == false) wait for some time || make a coffee;

[image]

4. Runs successfully. As for me, next time I ran with android studio , it run smoothly

Answer (score 1):

run your project through Xcode, not from Xcode or Android Studio. it will show  different error message.

when I run the Flutter project using Xcode, the error message was

> "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock..."

to solve this, I run `pod install` on the ios folder. run these 2 commands below on your terminal

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the solutions here and for me the simplest works:
move you Android Studio in the trash, download it and reinstall. for me the problem was with Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch but I got there with several updates. a clean install solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In My iPad case, It showed a white screen after compiling in the installing step for 5-10 minutes & it worked at the end without doing anything

Comment: Happening same in my case, have you figured it out why it took 5-10 minutes to before launching the application?

Comment: No I haven't figured out the reason

Answer (score 0):

in case you are running your flutter app on iOS by **Wireless debug**, you may have to wait 10 minutes until it's ready.

Answer (score -4):

Try updating your Xcode and MacOS to the latest versions.

Comment: If it is just a suggestion, please post it in the comments instead

Comment: It's a solution

Comment: I didn't downvote it :) As I said, I don't want to. I'm not surprised someone else did. Please read the community guidelines to post an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer