# How I can fix libobjc.A.dylib is being read from process memory. in Flutter ios

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-ios

I got this error and my app show white screen for about 30sec before it work
[image]

I'm trying to run my ios app in flutter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Observatory not discovered after 30 seconds. Error launching application on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69140504/ios-observatory-not-discovered-after-30-seconds-error-launching-application-on)

Comment: Please include the error message as a text within your question. Then you would have already noticed that this question has been answered