# Flutter IOS debug build installs the app on a real device but fails to initialize dart VM server

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, ipad

Flutter IOS debug build installs the app on a real device but fails to initialize dart VM server within 30 seconds and fails to run the app with error message :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on User's iPad in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: FQ********
Xcode build done.                                           25.7s
The Dart VM Service was not discovered after 30 seconds. This is taking much longer than expected...
(lldb) process interrupt
error: Failed to halt process: Halt timed out. State = running
Error launching application on User's iPad.
Exited
```

But when I try to install on the device with XCode or with simulator, it builds and works fine. I tried solutions on the the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69140504/ios-observatory-not-discovered-after-30-seconds-error-launching-application-on) on stackoverflow with different issue, but none of them have no avail to fix the problem.

I have tried with IPad pro 11 inch 2020 and IPhone 11 pro with the same WIFI network. And I am using Macbook M1 pro 14 inch 2021 base model. I've been using real IOS devices for more than a year with the same project. But about a month ago it started giving me the error.

When I try to build with a real device, the app doesn't ask local network permission nor notification permission. I've tried with different projects and it had the same error. Also I created a new flutter project with 0 dependencies, it gave me the same error but after I ran the app with XCode for two times it started working. But after I added dependencies from the first project that I ran into problem with, I started getting the same error. But the weird thing is when I use Flutter release mode, it works fine with any project. (By the way I have enabled wireless debug on XCode with both of the real devices I have mentioned earlier. But no difference with debug builds.)

XCode version : Version 14.3 (14E222b)

Podfile :

```
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        # config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
          '$(inherited)',
          
          ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
          'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
          
          ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
          'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
            
          ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
          'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
          ]
      end
    end
  end

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Flutter doctor verbose :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale en-MN)
    • Flutter version 3.10.1 on channel stable at /Users/gantushig/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d3d8effc68 (9 days ago), 2023-05-16 17:59:05 -0700
    • Engine revision b4fb11214d
    • Dart version 3.0.1
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gantushig/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.64.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Gantushig’s iPad (mobile) • 00008027-000C684A0A08402E • ios            • iOS 16.4.1 20E252
    • macOS (desktop)           • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.126

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Flutter run verbose last few lines :

```
[  +52 ms] [ 95%] GeneratingApplicationMap
[ +327 ms] [100%] InstallComplete
[ +987 ms] [100%] Installed package build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app
[  +99 ms] ------ Debug phase ------
[        ] Starting debug of 00008027-000C684A0A08402E (J418AP, iPad Pro 2G (11" Cell), iphoneos, arm64e, 16.4.1, 20E252) a.k.a. 'Gantushig’s iPad' connected
through USB...
[+1026 ms] [  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[  +27 ms] [ 95%] Developer disk image mounted successfully
[  +23 ms] Symbol Path: /Users/gantushig/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/16.4.1 (20E252) arm64e/Symbols
[ +457 ms] [100%] Connecting to remote debug server
[        ] -------------------------
[  +99 ms] (lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/B9863F2D-673A-40A5-9D48-5C384D397A22/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-00008027_000C684A0A08402E'
[        ] Executing commands in '/tmp/B9863F2D-673A-40A5-9D48-5C384D397A22/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-00008027_000C684A0A08402E'.
[        ] (lldb)     platform select remote-'ios' --sysroot '/Users/gantushig/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/16.4.1 (20E252) arm64e/Symbols'
[        ]   Platform: remote-ios
[        ]  Connected: no
[        ]    Sysroot: /Users/gantushig/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/16.4.1 (20E252) arm64e/Symbols
[        ]   SDK Path: "/Users/gantushig/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/16.4.1 (20E252) arm64e/Symbols"
[        ] (lldb)     target create "/Users/gantushig/projects/soyohon/soyohon_mobile/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app"
[+6149 ms] Current executable set to '/Users/gantushig/projects/soyohon/soyohon_mobile/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app' (arm64).
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_device_app="/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9191066D-06EC-41D9-A945-7BBDAB5CEBA1/Runner.app"
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_connect_url="connect://127.0.0.1:59678"
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_output_path=""
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_error_path=""
[        ] (lldb)     target modules search-paths add /usr "/Users/gantushig/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/16.4.1 (20E252) arm64e/Symbols/usr"
/System "/Users/gantushig/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/16.4.1 (20E252) arm64e/Symbols/System"
"/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9191066D-06EC-41D9-A945-7BBDAB5CEBA1" "/Users/gantushig/projects/soyohon/soyohon_mobile/build/ios/iphoneos"
"/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9191066D-06EC-41D9-A945-7BBDAB5CEBA1" "/Users/gantushig/projects/soyohon/soyohon_mobile/build/ios/iphoneos" /Developer
"/Users/gantushig/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/16.4.1 (20E252) arm64e/Symbols/Developer"
[  +34 ms] (lldb)     command script import "/tmp/B9863F2D-673A-40A5-9D48-5C384D397A22/fruitstrap_00008027_000C684A0A08402E.py"
[   +3 ms] (lldb)     command script add -f fruitstrap_00008027_000C684A0A08402E.connect_command connect
[        ] (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_00008027_000C684A0A08402E.run_command run
[        ] (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_00008027_000C684A0A08402E.autoexit_command autoexit
[        ] (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_00008027_000C684A0A08402E.safequit_command safequit
[        ] (lldb)     connect
[  +32 ms] (lldb)     run
[ +198 ms] success
[        ] Application launched on the device. Waiting for Dart VM Service url.
[+30005 ms] The Dart VM Service was not discovered after 30 seconds. This is taking much longer than expected...
[   +8 ms] (lldb) process interrupt
[        ] error: Failed to halt process: Halt timed out. State = running
[+2073 ms] (lldb) Process 2598 exited with status = -1 (0xffffffff) lost connection
[   +3 ms] ios-deploy exited with code 0
[   +6 ms] Installing and launching... (completed in 56.6s)
[        ] Error launching application on Gantushig’s iPad.
[   +2 ms] "flutter run" took 96,019ms.
[   +3 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:757:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +259 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 253ms
[        ] Running 1 shutdown hook
[   +3 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

Flutter pubspec yaml file :

```
name: flutter_app
description: Social app.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+36

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^5.0.0
  rive: ^0.11.1
  provider: ^6.0.2
  cookie_jar: ^4.0.2
  dio_cookie_manager: ^3.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  flutter_form_builder: ^9.0.0-dev.3
  form_builder_validators: ^9.0.0-dev.2
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.0+1
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.28
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.9
  image_picker: ^0.8.3
  image_cropper: ^3.0.0
  pinput: ^2.2.7
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^14.0.0+1
  socket_io_client: ^2.0.1
  location: ^4.4.0
  avatar_glow: ^2.0.2
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  skeletons: ^0.0.3
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.6
  android_intent_plus: ^4.0.0
  device_apps: ^2.2.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.2
  external_app_launcher: ^3.1.0
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  water_drop_nav_bar: ^2.2.0+5
  connectivity_plus: ^4.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.3.0
  intl: ^0.18.0
  freezed_annotation: ^2.2.0
  json_annotation: ^4.8.0
  collection: ^1.17.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.0
  webview_flutter_android: ^3.7.0
  webview_flutter_wkwebview: ^3.4.3

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/logo.png
  color: '#FA4251'

  android_12:
    image: assets/images/android_splash_icon.png
    icon_background_color: '#FA4251'
    image_dark: assets/images/android_splash_icon.png
    icon_background_color_dark: '#FA4251'

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  freezed: ^2.3.2
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  hive_generator: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  json_serializable: ^6.6.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/rive_models/simple-loader.riv
    - assets/rive_models/find_user.riv
    - assets/rive_models/new_file.riv
    - assets/rive_models/spaceship_pull_refresh.riv
    - assets/rive_models/
    - assets/images/christmas_logo.png
    - assets/images/astrology/
    - assets/images/svg/back.svg
    - assets/images/svg/icons/shopping-bag.svg
    - assets/images/svg/
    - assets/images/back_image/
    - assets/images/logo.png
    - assets/images/membership/
    - assets/images/android_splash_icon.png
    - assets/images/mission/icons/
    - assets/images/mission/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/gif/

  fonts:
    - family: Rubik
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Light.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-LightItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Regular.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Medium.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-MediumItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-SemiBold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Bold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-BoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-ExtraBold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-Black.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 900
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik/Rubik-BlackItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 900
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 900
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 900
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Thin.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-ThinItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Light.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-LightItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-MediumItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-BoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Black.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 900
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Black.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 900
    - family: Inter
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Thin.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-ExtraLight.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Light.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Regular.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Medium.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-SemiBold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Bold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-ExtraBold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Black.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 900
    - family: Source Sans Pro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-LightItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-BoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Black.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 900
        - asset: assets/fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-BlackItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 900
```

It should work fine. And I really need to enable this feautre since it is way more convenient with testing with real devices.

Comment: For iOS did you create development certificates for run on real device?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have created development certificates and an Apple developer account too. The provision signing profile has been set.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by resetting my iPad and doing a software update. Now my IOS builds are working fine. But now and then when new IOS updates are released, I get a build error. I am not sure if it's flutter related problem or if is it with IOS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using wirelessly on iOS device and had a same issue.

I tried uninstall the app, It works for me.

And then I found a github issue comment, it maybe useful.

jmagman commented on Jun 28, 2022 at:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72161

1. The flood of reports of this issue usually coincides with the iOS updates. Long app launch times is a commonly reported problem when there's a pending iOS update on your test device, or when your test device is running a newer OS than the one shipped with Xcode. It's also commonly reported right after you upgrade your test OS because Xcode can get stuck trying to copy the developer image over to the device. Many of these reports are that it works on one device and not on another device running the same OS. Frankly there's not much Flutter can do to work around this when the problem is between the test device and Xcode.
2. Make sure Xcode is updated and your iOS device is updated. You can also try opening ios/Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode and running your app from there to unwedge it.
3. You can also try running flutter clean to clean Xcode's build folder (DerivedData).
4. People are also reporting uninstalling the app first may help. We tried that in our own CI system and added an --uninstall-first flag to run and drive, but it didn't work for us, but maybe it will for you. [
5. People are also reporting uninstalling the app first may help. We tried that in our own CI system and added an --uninstall-first flag to run and drive, but it didn't work for us, but maybe it will for you.
6. You also may be hitting "iproxy cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified" #42969. See if there's a pop up under your windows.